# open a new browser tab in background programmatically

Tags: javascript, web-applications, background, tabs

## Problem

I'm using a web-based feed reader, [TinyTinyRSS](http://tt-rss.org). When sifting through the feed lists, I'd like to open interesting articles in new tabs - but *in the background*, because I want to read them only after I went through all feed items.

TT-RSS has a shortcut key "o" to open the article in a new tab, but it opens the tab in the foreground (`window.open`).

The question is now: To fix TT-RSS, I need to know **how to open a background tab from javascript**. It'd be awesome if the solution worked across browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari).

I understand the privacy issue about that, but having it enabled for one certified webpage is ok.

## Existing (bad) solutions

### Firefox

In `about:config`, set `browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground` to `true`.
This opens all the tabs from pages in the background, which is not what I want - I want it only for the one application/website.

### Chrome

Chrome has a [shytab extension](http://www.chromeextensions.org/tabs/shytab/). Works in chrome only and is for all pages.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the fix in `about:config`.  You can use Firefox profiles to create a second profile to work with pages which need this global settings.  A very clumsy workaround until Mozilla gets around to fix the bug which is open for over 6 years now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back when popup ads were a thing, this was called a "popunder" window. Popunders used to do something like this:

```
var popupWindow = window.open(...);
popupWindow.blur();
window.focus();
```

Popup blocking kind of messed around with what does and doesn't work, though- your mileage may vary.

Comment: -1 does not work in firefox as the question asked. No idea why this is the accepted answer.

Comment: As I mentioned, popup blocking is evolving and what may have worked in 2011 may not always work.

Comment: A solution, by the way, was to do alert() after window.open(). Super ugly, but for a website that I only use myself... I got used to pressing space to close the alert window every time. So that works for me.