# HTML - how to open a link in the background?

Tags: html, browser, tabs

I am browsing some websites, I can click (for example in Chrome) on the link with the right button and choose OPEN IN THE NEW TAB -> the tab is opened, but in the background (the current tab stays as the main tab).

I am trying to do with the link - I added to the link the attribute `target="_blank"`, but always as the main tab is displayed the new one - not the tab from which I opened the new tab.

Is there any way, how to do that?

**EDIT:** What I am trying:

```
javascript.js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
      ...
    })

<a href="http://www.google.com" id="id_attribute">link</a>
```

But the page is always opened in the same window...

Comment: Check these questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386208/open-a-new-browser-tab-in-background-programmatically

Comment: Here's the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522565/how-to-stay-on-current-window-when-the-link-opens-in-new-tab

Comment: try to search better before posting duplicate questions

Answer (score -1):

You must remove the link's target attribute:

```
  $('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```

Then it will stay in the same window without changing to the new one that opens by clicking the link.

Comment: Thanks man. Please, take a look at the updated OP. The problem is, that the new page is always opened in the same tab.

Comment: This makes the link open in the current tab/window, rather than in a new tab/window in the background.