# Can I used javascript to open a new tab in the browser, but not switch to it?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Can I used javascript to open a new tab in the browser, but not switch to it?

Now i use:

```
<script>window.open("url")</script>
```

UPD
May be I'm stupid, but

```
<script>
function openWin(){
    popupWindow = window.open("url");
    popupWindow.blur();
}
openWin()
</script>
```

dos'n work... It's opening tab, but focus on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [open a new browser tab in background programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386208/open-a-new-browser-tab-in-background-programmatically)

Comment: and [Open a new tab in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10812628/218196).

Comment: and [Open a new tab with javascript but stay on current tab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6213807/218196) and probably some more [of those](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+open+tab+in+background).

Comment: ...and an awful practice. I can't think that there is a "great" reason to do this.

Comment: It's up to the browser, not you, whether or not new tabs are focused.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an event (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click) to do this, eg:-

```
var event = document.createEvent("MyEvent");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";
event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(event);
```

[event.initMouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent)

Comment: I don't use any click I I load a page that opens a new tab, the previously selected by the user.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript blur event takes focus away from the window, so you can open a new window and then take focus away from it I believe.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_blur.asp